# Python Tkinter retrieving input of multiple values

Tags: python, input, tkinter

Here is the below code and I am having issues surrounding retrieving input from multiple values.  I have been working on this issue for some time now without any suggest.  I do appreciate the insight; however, I am at wits end.  If someone could please provide a fix to my code I would be ever so grateful.

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe

from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title('HADOUKEN!')

def retrieve_input(text,chkvar,v):
  textarea_result = text.get()
  checkbox_result = chkvar.get()
  radiobutton_result = v.get()
  root.destroy()

text = Text(root, height=16, width=40)
scroll = Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)

text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

text.grid(sticky=E)
scroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ns')

text.focus()

chkvar = IntVar()
chkvar.set(0)
c = Checkbutton(root, text="CaseIt", variable=chkvar)
c.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

v = ""
radio1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Src", variable=v, value=1)
radio1.grid(row=1,column=0)
radio1.focus()

radio2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Dst", variable=v, value=2)
radio2.grid(row=2,column=0)

b1 = Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: retrieve_input(text,chkvar,v))
b1.grid(row=1, column=2)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Hadoken.gif"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()

print textarea_result
print checkbox_result
print radiobutton_result
```

Comment: The traceback will tell you what the error is and what line it is on. Have you tried working through these errors at all?

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems in your code, though most of them produce errors that should be self-explanatory. My suggestion is to start over with just a single widget, and get the logic working for that to reduce the number of things that could go wrong. Once you have that working, you can then add one widget at a time as you learn how to use that widget.

That being said, here are the most obvious errors that I spotted:

**The first problem** is that you are incorrectly calling the `get` method of a text widget. This method is documented to take two arguments -- a starting index and an ending index. Since tkinter always adds a trailing newline, you want to get everything from the start ("1.0"), to the end minus one character ("end-1c"). Thus, you should be getting the value in the text widget like this:

```
textarea_result = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

**The second problem** is that `retrieve_input` seems to assume that `v` is a StringVar or IntVa since you are calling a `get` method on it. Given that you are using that variable with a radiobutton, that's what it should be. However, you created it as a normal variable, which of course doesn't have a `get` method. You should declare it as one of the special tkinter variables:

```
...
v = StringVar()
radio1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Src", variable=v, value=1)
...
```

**The third problem** is, `retrieve_input` is setting local variables. If you want to set the value of global variables (which I assume, since you are later trying to access them after the widget is destroyed), then you need to declare them as global:

```
def retrieve_input(text,chkvar,v):
  global textarea_result, checkbox_result, radiobutton_result
  ...
```

Comment: Wow finally man thanks a ton only problem now is my radio button displays both radio buttons being selected when the gui loads I need to figure out how to put a focus say on radio button 1

Comment: figured out the radio needed to have radio1.select()